# How to click CSS with a space using Selenium Webdriver

Tags: java, css, intellij-idea, selenium-webdriver, browser-automation

I am trying to click the `CSS` below

```
html body.FormBackground form#LookupForm div#Panel1 table tbody tr td div#GridContainerDiv div table#DataGrid tbody tr.GridSelectedRow td.GridRow
```

So far I have tried

```
@FindBy(css = "#DataGrid\\tbody\\tr.GridSelectedRow > td.GridRow")
```

and

```
@FindBy(css = "#DataGrid tbody tr.GridSelectedRow > td.GridRow")
```

But neither of the above attempts seem to work. HTML is below.

```
<tbody>
 <tr ondblclick="$HRnet('DataGrid').dblClick(); " gender_id="f6611f8a-8e80-41e6-a14c-fa8e25be3065" class="GridUnSelectedRow">
    <td class="GridRow">Female</td>
 </tr>
 <tr ondblclick="$HRnet('DataGrid').dblClick(); " gender_id="3ef09fb8-4d5d-43d2-abc0-2506616ef83e" class="GridSelectedRow">
    <td class="GridRow">Male</td>
 </tr>
 <tr nofocus="true">
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
 </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: can you please post the complete HTML code for the table.That will help us to get more details on the problem.

Comment: if you want to click the td of selected row then use the below css,

@FindBy(css = "#DataGrid tr.GridSelectedRow > td.GridRow")

Comment: Do I have to specify if I want it to select male or female? And if so how do I do that through CSS?

Comment: Which element are you trying to click?

Comment: I would suggest you spend some time reading some tutorials on CSS and trying more things. This is at least the second question like this that you've asked recently. If you don't learn how to do this yourself, you are going to have to ask every time you run into something like this. Here's a couple links to get you started but there are million more on the web. https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#selectors https://saucelabs.com/resources/selenium/css-selectors

Comment: Thanks I appreciate it, I'll have a look. I'm trying to click Male. Right now its only clicking female which I guess means I'm just not being specific enough with my CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on what you've shared it looks like this should work but it will return multiple rows so you'll need to decide which one you want to click

```
@FindBy(css = "#DataGrid td.GridRow")
```